# Spring Boot + ProcessRunner + @Values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application that calls through an ApplicationRunner class a ProcessRunner Class.

The example below, SetupRunner is the one been called by the ApplicationRunner.

The application has an "application.yml" properties file.

The caller sees its values correctly, but the class that it's been called doesn't. The same happens with environment variables.

How do I preserver properties values and environment variables?

Thank you

```
@Component
public class SetupRunner {
    private @Value("${aa.bb.cc}") String aaBbCc;
    ...
    LOGGER.warn(aaBbCc); // prints correctly
    ...
    ((Processor) Class.forName(bean.getBeanClassName()).newInstance()).process(repository);
    ...
}
```

```
@ProcessRunner(...)
public class SSORegistrationProcessor extends Processor {
  private @Value("${aa.bb.cc}") String aaBbCc;
  @Override
  public void process(DataRepository data) throws ProcessorException {
    LOGGER.warn(aaBbCc); // is null
  }
}
```

Comment: why should `((Processor) Class.forName(bean.getBeanClassName()).newInstance())` be aware of any "spring stuff"?? ;)

Comment: try: `bean.process(...)` ;)

Comment: Sorry I missed this information. bean is of the type BeanDefinition, resulted from a scan.

Comment: ..yes, `bean.getBeanClassName()` looks like a string... "`@Value`  ... can be used for injecting values into fields in **Spring-managed beans**" [ref](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation) ... `SSORegistrationProcessor` does not look like one!

Comment: I've just stopped using the ProccessRunner to make it work, but I still not getting...